# Saving data into multiple tables from the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've got a ViewModel that includes multiple models:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  Music.Models.Organizations Organizations {get; set;}
  Music.Models.People People {get; set;}
}
```

When the appropriate fields are filled in on my view by the user and the user pressed the submit button, I want to save the changes to the appropriate tables in my controller: (I've got an instance of MyViewModel named db)

```
[HttpPost] public ActionResult Submit(MyViewModel model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    db. //what do I do here?
  }
}
```

In tutorials and such, I've only seen one model at a time being used, therefore they can just do something like

```
db.People.Add(model);
db.SaveChanges();
```

With data being saved to multiple tables when the submit button is pressed by the user, I'm not sure how to save changes to each table in my ViewModel.  Any assistance would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd just save the models that are properties on the view model.  Using your example from a tutorial, if you were going to add a new record for each of those two, it might be something like this:

```
db.People.Add(model.People);
db.Organizations.Add(model.Organizations);
db.SaveChanges();
```

You can make all the additions/modifications/etc. that you want within the database context (the `db` object and its properties) and when you call `.SaveChanges()` they will all get sent to the database.  In the above code that database call would end up being two `INSERT` statements.

Comment: zomg...I was thinking so hard on a one line solution, didn't even consider needing two different statements. Thanks very much!

Comment: Instead of creating a new ViewModel for each page that only includes the models which will be used for that page, couldn't I just create one context file which includes all of my models and use that for each page?  Do yo know if there's any efficiency differences between the two?

Comment: @SantasNotReal: That doesn't sound like a good idea, unless I'm misunderstanding what you're asking.  Populating every page with *all* possible data regardless of what that page actually needs would be very inefficient.  Or just having one giant catch-all object with a ton of `null` values for the data not needed by that page is a bit sloppy and difficult to maintain.  It's best to keep each view model tailored to the page (or pages) which uses it.  As a general rule, many small classes are better than one big class.